# Trying to install Tensorflow in Anaconda on my PC

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am in the process of installing Tensorflow in Anaconda on my PC running Windows 10, GTX970, Visual Studio 2015 Community.  As I understand, the GPU version of Tensorflow is now available for Windows.

I successfully installed the latest Anaconda with Python 3.6, 64 bit.

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community.

I installed CUDA 8.0 following the CUDA instructions.

I created a second environment (tensorflowgpu) with conda.  I installed Python 3.5.3 in that environment.  I activated that environment.

I tried to install Tensorflow with this command: **pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl**

I got the following error message: **tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl** is not a supported wheel on this platform.

There are several places I could check for problems:

1. Verify that CUDA was a good download
2. Check environment variables (cuDNN, etc.)
3. Is environment set up properly?
4. Should I be using Python 3.5 instead of 3.5.3?
5. Something else

Does the error message suggest where I should begin?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [TensorFlow installation documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) currently has the incorrect URL for the Windows PIP packages. Instead of https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl (which refers to a non-existent file), use https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (change `x86_64` to `amd64`).

Comment: That important change got Tensorflow loaded into the environment, Thank you.

Comment: I checked that it was a good install with the following short program:import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))

Comment: Got the following response:

Comment: The response is too long to paste here.  Here are the last few lines:

Comment: Free memory: 3.31GiB
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
>>> print(sess.run(hello))

Comment: Those look like normal log messages that are printed when you import the TensorFlow library.

Comment: Apparently, the test failed.  How can I determine why?  Thanks

Comment: The last line you quoted has `print(sess.run(hello))`... what happens when you try to run that statement?

Comment: It was supposed to print: Hello, TensorFlow!

Comment: It responded with: Unable to initialize device PRN

Comment: I ran the same small check program again and got the same output. It's important to note that the cursor remained flashing at the end of the last output line.  It did not go to >>>.  Perhaps it isn't finished but it's taking a long time. Pretty slow for a GPU, lol.

Comment: This is strange or perhaps it isn't:  I pressed the Return key, it printed Hello, Tensorflow! like it was supposed to.

Comment: Am I required to hit the return to activate the Print command?  I thought it would finish by itself.  Thanks.

Comment: I think that's "working as intended". Perhaps you copied and pasted the original code snippet without the final return character? In general, the Python REPL requires you to press return after each statement if you want to run that statement.

Comment: I think my question has been answered. Thank you mrry

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [nightlybuild](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) to my hard disk and

```
pip install --upgrade C:\tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

works for me.